# How to do efficient k-nearest neighbor calculation in Matlab

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, nearest-neighbor

I'm doing data analysis using k-nearest neighbor algorithm in Matlab. My data consists of about 11795 x 88 data matrix, where the rows are observations and columns are variables.

My task is to find k-nearest neighbors for n selected test points. Currently I'm doing it with the following logic:

> FOR all the test points
>
> ```
>    LOOP all the data and find the k-closest neighbors (by euclidean distance)
> ```

In other words, I loop all the n test points. For each test point I search the data (which excludes the test point itself) for k-nearest neighbors by euclidean distance. For each test point this takes approximately k x 11794 iterations. So the whole process takes about n x k x 11794 iterations. If n = 10000 and k = 7, this would be approximately 825,6 million iterations.

Is there a more efficient way to calculate the k-nearest neighbors? Most of the computation is going to waste now, because my algorithm simply:

calculates the euclidean distance to all the other points, picks up the closest and excludes the closest point from further consideration -->  calculates the euclidean distance to all the other points and picks up the closest --> etc. -->  etc.

Is there a smart way to get rid of this 'waste calculation'?

Currently this process takes about 7 hours in my computer (3.2 GHz, 8 GB RAM, 64-bit Win 7)... :(

Here is some of the logic illustrated explicitly (this is not all my code, but this is the part that eats up performance):

```
for i = 1:size(testpoints, 1) % Loop all the test points 
    neighborcandidates = all_data_excluding_testpoints; % Use the rest of the data excluding the test points in search of the k-nearest neighbors 
    testpoint = testpoints(i, :); % This is the test point for which we find k-nearest neighbors
    kneighbors = []; % Store the k-nearest neighbors here.
    for j = 1:k % Find k-nearest neighbors
        bdist = Inf; % The distance of the closest neighbor
        bind = 0; % The index of the closest neighbor
        for n = 1:size(neighborcandidates, 1) % Loop all the candidates
            if pdist([testpoint; neighborcandidates(n, :)]) < bdist % Check the euclidean distance
                bdist = pdist([testpoint; neighborcandidates(n, :)]); % Update the best distance so far
                bind = n; % Save the best found index so far
            end
        end
        kneighbors = [kneighbors; neighborcandidates(bind, :)]; % Save the found neighbour
        neighborcandidates(bind, :) = []; % Remove the neighbor from further consideration 
    end
end
```

Comment: add a small example to illustrate clearly.

Comment: +1 Roger that @Nishant =)

Comment: That's a lot of loops - what happens if you just run `pdist2` on the entire matrix as one input and then the subset of `n` observations as the second input matrix? Can your computer handle that / do you know how long that takes? Because then you get the pairwise distance for all the elements you're looking for in one line and find the top `k` for each of those `n` observations should be quite simple...

Comment: +1 Hi @Dan no I haven't tried that =) I will give it a try and let you know what came up ;)

Comment: Hi @Dan I used `pdist2`to compute the distances. It took only less than a minute. Rest should be no problem =) So that's a significant improvement =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi No problem, I've added an answer showing how I'd use it

Comment: @jjepsuomi Also see my answer for using Matlab's built in `knnsearch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pdist2`:

```
A = rand(20,5);             %// This is your 11795 x 88
B = A([1, 12, 4, 8], :);    %// This is your n-by-88 subset, i.e. n=4 in this case
n = size(B,1);

D = pdist2(A,B);
[~, ind] = sort(D);
kneighbours = ind(2:2+k, :);
```

Now you can use `kneighbours` to index a row in `A`. Note that the columns of `kneighbours` correspond to the rows of `B`

But since you're already dipping into the stats toolbox with `pdist` why not just use Matlab's `knnsearch`?

```
kneighbours_matlab = knnsearch(A,B,'K',k+1);
```

note that `kneighbours` is the same as `kneighbours_matlab(:,2:end)'`

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! =) When I'm done implementing the solution I will post the estimated running time =)

Comment: Hi @Dan I decided to use the `pdist2` approach. The running time is now about 30 seconds =) so about x840 times faster running time x)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with specific matlab functions but you can remove k from your formula.

There is a well-known selection algorithm that

1. takes array A (of size n) and number k as input.
2. Gives permutation of array A such that k-th biggest/smallest element is at k-th place.
3. Smaller elements are to the left, bigger are to the right.

e.g.

```
A=2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9; k=5

output = 2,4,1,3,5,10,6,8,7,9
```

This is done in O(n) steps and doesn't depend on k.

**EDIT1:** You can also precompute all distances as it looks like its the place where you spend most of the computation. It will be roughly a 800M matrix so that shouldnt be the issue on modern machines.

Comment: Now that I took a look at the question. You should try EDIT suggestion first as its way easier to implement. Remember that dist[i,j] = dist[j,i]

Comment: +1 Appreciate the help! =)  I will try the suggestions and let everyone know the time improvement =)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will speed up the code, but it removes the inner two loops

```
for i = 1:size(testpoints, 1) % //Loop all the test points 
    temp = repmat(testpoints(i,:),size(neighborcandidates, 1),1);
    euclead_dist = (sum((temp - neighborcandidates).^2,2).^(0.5));
    [sort_dist ind] = sort(euclead_dist);
    lowest_k_ind = ind(1:k);
    kneighbors = neighborcandidates(lowest_k_ind, :);
    neighborcandidates(lowest_k_ind, :) = [];
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
adjk = adj;

for i=1:k-1 
adj_k = adj_k*adj; 
end

kneigh = find(adj_k(n,:)>0)
```

given a node n and an index k?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a faster code in the context of Matlab. You can also try parallel functions, data index, and approximate nearest neighbor algorithms to be theoretically more efficient.

```
% a slightly faster way to find k nearest neighbors in matlab
% find neighbors for data Y from data X

m=size(X,1);
n=size(Y,1);
IDXs_out=zeros(n,k);

distM=(repmat(X(:,1),1,n)-repmat(Y(:,1)',m,1)).^2;
for d=2:size(Y,2)
    distM=distM+(repmat(X(:,d),1,n)-repmat(Y(:,d)',m,1)).^2;
end
distM=sqrt(distM);
for i=1:k
    [~,idx]=min(distM,[],1);
    id=sub2ind(size(distM),idx',(1:n)');
    distM(id)=inf;
    IDXs_out(:,i)=idx';
end
```